# what value is returned when there are 2 values with highest value in max function of R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with customer id and with breakup of sales by country. I am supposed to assign the country to a particular subscriber where his sales are highest. This is how I am achiev

```
sonycountry$Country_New <- colnames(sonycountry[,2:17])[apply(sonycountry[,2:17],1,which.max)]
```

Now I am suppose to apply country as US wherever sales by region are equal which is assigned randomly according to my previous code

Can anybody suggest me how to achieve it ??

Comment: Please post few lines of input data and expected output.  Instead of looping over the rows, you can use `colnames(sonycountry[,2:17])[max.col(sonycountry[,2:17], 'first')]`

Comment: In case of ties, if you want to return all the columns, may be `apply(sonycountry[,2:17], 1, function(x) toString(names(sonycountry)[2:17][x==max(x)])))`

Comment: from the help of wich.max: "For a logical vector x, which.min(x) and which.max(x) return the index of the first FALSE or TRUE, respectively." Please read the help of the functions in r first. There are some dangers in just using them

Comment: As @phiver said your current code does not randomly pick the max. Based on your description I think you need to return the countries of all max values per customer id and if US in one of them you just keep that. But, what happens if you have multiple countries and US is not one of them? Up to you do decide that filtering part.